# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Can someone help with the format of some data.

Here is my code:

```
initializeBoxWithIconListAndTitle( "title":"Test Title", "items":[ {"icon":"fa fa-phone", "html":'Phone'}, {"icon":"fa fa-home", "html":'Web'}, {"icon":"fa fa-map-marker", "html":'Map'}, {"icon":"fa fa-envelope", "html":'Email'} ]);

function initializeBoxWithIconListAndTitle(data)
{
    var classname = '.box2';
    $(classname + ' .box-title').html(data.title);
    $.each(data.items, function() {
        $(classname + ' .box-body').append('<p><i class="' + this.icon + '"></i>' + this.html +'</p>');
    });
}
```

This is the error that I am getting in the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Can I please have some help with this?

Comment: Your "object" doesn't have an opening brace. Or a closing one for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object that is passed to initializeBoxWithIconListAndTitle is malformed. It is missing the braces `{}` You have to send an object like this

```
initializeBoxWithIconListAndTitle({
  "title": "Test Title",
  "items": [{
    "icon": "fa fa-phone",
    "html": 'Phone'
  }, {
    "icon": "fa fa-home",
    "html": 'Web'
  }, {
    "icon": "fa fa-map-marker",
    "html": 'Map'
  }, {
    "icon": "fa fa-envelope",
    "html": 'Email'
  }]
});
```